# How can I sum form variants in php?

Tags: php, forms

I send my form data to a php page such as:
question1
question2
.
.
.
and more.

I wanna sum this variants but i dont know.
I use this code but not work:

```
$total=0;
for ($i=1; $i<=$countc; $i++) {
    $sag = "question" . $i;
    $_POST[$sag];
    $total = $total+$_POST[$sag];
    echo $total;   // I wanna show sum of all form vars.
}
```

my form:

```
  echo "
      <form method='post' action='result.php?result=$name' />
      <input name='$name' style='visibility:hidden' /><br />
";
  for ($i=0;$i<$countq;$i++){
  echo "${'countquestion'.$i}<br />";

  for ($j=0;$j<$countc;$j++){
echo "${'countchoice'.$j.'countquestion'.$i}
<input type='radio' value='${'countchoicepoint'.$j.'countquestion'.$i}'    name='question$i' /><br />
";
                          }
                      }
      echo "
       <input type='submit' value='sabt' />
        ";
```

Comment: what's the post array look like?

Comment: Are you using POST or GET? Can you add the <form> tag you use? Preferably copied from the web browser "View Source"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use array_sum to add an array of numeric values.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

As for your code, it would be better to use a foreach loop

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($_POST["answers"] as $question=>$answer) $total+=$answer;
```

Assuming you sore all anwers in $_POST["answers"] variable; if you store only answers in $_POST, you can use:

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($_POST["answers"] as $answer) $total+=$answer;
```

But this can be done easily using array_sum (for both associative and non-associative arrays.

To concatenati it into a string, you may use implode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php